# react-native run-android starting metro server from wrong folder

Tags: react-native

[image]When I run the following command from my project's root directory it don't start metro server from the project directory. Rather it starts from project directory->node_modules->react-native directory.

```
react-native run-android
```

Please help me by what wrong things may happen for this scenario.

Comment: can any one please help with this question?